# Heroku push rejected because gem checksum failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler

I've been pushing updates to my app successfully all week. This morning I went to push another update (just some CSS changes) and suddenly I'm my pushes are being rejected because the checksums on numerous gems seem to be randomly failing. I say randomly because each time I've tried pushing, the failing checksums are for different gems.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Bundler, RubyGems, or Heroku, but those all seem like obvious candidates. I can't find any mention of similar issues and Heroku seems to have eliminated the ability to submit a support ticket unless you pay for an enterprise support plan.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the log from the last attempt:

```
$ git push heroku master

Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.55 KiB | 1.55 MiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack app detected
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack: Installed nginx/1.5.7 to app/bin
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack: Added start-nginx to app/bin
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack: Default mime.types copied to app/config/
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack: Default config copied to app/config.
remote: -----> Image-Optim Buildback app detected
remote: -----> Adding Item-Optim binaries
remote: cp: omitting directory ‘jpegoptim’
remote:        ‘advpng’ -> ‘/tmp/build_c96d18fd0f8c4e48e3ec30ced800682d/vendor/image-optim/advpng’
remote:        ‘gifsicle’ -> ‘/tmp/build_c96d18fd0f8c4e48e3ec30ced800682d/vendor/image-optim/gifsicle’
remote:        ‘jpegtran’ -> ‘/tmp/build_c96d18fd0f8c4e48e3ec30ced800682d/vendor/image-optim/jpegtran’
remote:        ‘optipng’ -> ‘/tmp/build_c96d18fd0f8c4e48e3ec30ced800682d/vendor/image-optim/optipng’
remote:        ‘pngcrush’ -> ‘/tmp/build_c96d18fd0f8c4e48e3ec30ced800682d/vendor/image-optim/pngcrush’
remote:        ‘jpegoptim/jpegoptim-cedar14’ -> ‘/tmp/build_c96d18fd0f8c4e48e3ec30ced800682d/vendor/image-optim/jpegoptim’
remote: -----> Adding image-optim binaries symlink to make them available in next buildpacks
remote: -----> Adding image-optim binaries to PATH
remote:        ‘image-optim.sh’ -> ‘/tmp/build_c96d18fd0f8c4e48e3ec30ced800682d/.profile.d/image-optim.sh’
remote: -----> Gemfile detected, adding image-optim config file
remote: ‘image_optim.yml’ -> ‘/tmp/build_c96d18fd0f8c4e48e3ec30ced800682d/.image_optim.yml’
remote: -----> Image-Optim binaries version
remote:        advancecomp v1.18 by Andrea Mazzoleni
remote:        LCDF Gifsicle 1.78
remote:        jpegoptim v1.4.2  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
remote:        libjpeg-turbo version 1.2.90 (build 20130305)
remote:        OptiPNG version 0.7.4
remote:         | pngcrush 1.7.15
remote: -----> ImageMagick app detected
remote: -----> Install ImageMagick
remote: -----> Extracting ImageMagick /app/tmp/cache/imagemagick-6.9.9-23.7z.tar.gz => /tmp/build_c96d18fd0f8c4e48e3ec30ced800682d/vendor
remote: -----> Writing policy file
remote: -----> Updating environment variables
remote: -----> ffmpeg app detected
remote: -----> Install ffmpeg
remote:        DOWNLOAD_URL =  https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
remote:        exporting PATH
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError The checksum of /info/erubi does not match the checksum provided by the server! Something is wrong (local checksum is "\"a080a1775e4c3f8b72707ef6a2e071b4\"", was expecting "\"5512cda1-50280\"")..
remote:        Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError The checksum of /info/crass does not match the checksum provided by the server! Something is wrong (local checksum is "\"a080a1775e4c3f8b72707ef6a2e071b4\"", was expecting "\"5512cda1-50280\"")..
remote:        Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError The checksum of /info/sass-listen does not match the checksum provided by the server! Something is wrong (local checksum is "\"a080a1775e4c3f8b72707ef6a2e071b4\"", was expecting "\"5512cda1-50280\"")..
remote:        The checksum of /info/et-orbi does not match the checksum provided by the
remote:        server! Something is wrong (local checksum is
remote:        "\"a080a1775e4c3f8b72707ef6a2e071b4\"", was expecting "\"5512cda1-50280\"").
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError The checksum of /info/erubi does not match the checksum provided by the server! Something is wrong (local checksum is "\"a080a1775e4c3f8b72707ef6a2e071b4\"", was expecting "\"5512cda1-50280\"")..
remote:        Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError The checksum of /info/crass does not match the checksum provided by the server! Something is wrong (local checksum is "\"a080a1775e4c3f8b72707ef6a2e071b4\"", was expecting "\"5512cda1-50280\"")..
remote:        Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError The checksum of /info/sass-listen does not match the checksum provided by the server! Something is wrong (local checksum is "\"a080a1775e4c3f8b72707ef6a2e071b4\"", was expecting "\"5512cda1-50280\"")..
remote:        The checksum of /info/et-orbi does not match the checksum provided by the
remote:        server! Something is wrong (local checksum is
remote:        "\"a080a1775e4c3f8b72707ef6a2e071b4\"", was expecting "\"5512cda1-50280\"").
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to fply.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/fply.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fply.git'
```

Comment: I am getting the same thing, just started happening out of nowhere.

Comment: I checked the status page for Heroku and RubyGems and neither report problems (yet).

Comment: Touched a file locally and pushed again, seems to be working again.

Comment: Just tried that and it went through this time. Hopefully that's the last of it